# How to force a client-side roam from one AP to another AP (same SSID) on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, wireless-networking, wifi-driver

Is there a way I can force a client-side roam from one AP to another AP on a Windows 10 workstation provided that both APs are within acceptable range? I just want to see if there's a way I can do it without having to walk around and wait for the driver to roam itself.

Note that this would be something different than a manual connect / disconnect of the Wi-Fi.

Comment: Im assuming this is a client "sticking" to one AP when you feel like it should have roamed to the second based off of signal strength?

Comment: What's the model of the wifi adapter you have?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I just want to force a roam to see if I get packet loss during the roam handshake process. I have the Netgear WNDA4100, but I'm interested about how to do this for more than just one model of Wi-Fi card.

Comment: The reason I was asking is because different models call the settings different things, they also handle the roam differently across different chipsets, manufacturers, drivers and operating systems. So all Information inbetween is relevant. Have you adjusted the "roaming aggressiveness" settings in Windows?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Yes, I see that setting in the adapter properties, but I can't seem to be able to "make it" roam.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `.bat` script that either does

Automatic Wi-Fi disconnect & reconnect (takes ~1 second in my setup):

```
netsh wlan disconnect
netsh wlan connect name=<your-profile-name--default-is-your-ssid>
```

or disabling the network adapter and re-enabling it (takes 8 seconds in my setup):

```
netsh interface set interface <your-interface-name-e-g-Wi-Fi> disabled
netsh interface set interface <your-interface-name-e-g-Wi-Fi> enabled
```